What is the proper way to stop and restart a service that is a "bundled daemon"?
There are some recent apps, e.g., Cisco Secure Client / AnyConnect  VPN service, where the service cannot be stopped/started using the LaunchControl.app.
For more control over what's running on the machine and when, I would like to be able to stop/start the service using the command line and make sure that it is loaded properly by checking its state using appropriate commands.
However, the method I have to stop the service results in me not being able to query the service status after I start the service back up.
What is the proper way to stop/start services for "bundled services" ??
To start, I check whether the service is running on or not:
$ launchctl print system/com.cisco.secureclient.vpn.service.agent
system/com.cisco.secureclient.vpn.service.agent = {
    active count = 1
    path = (submitted by smd.303)
    type = Submitted
    managed_by = com.apple.xpc.ServiceManagement
    state = running

    program identifier = Contents/MacOS/vpnagentd (mode: 2)
    parent bundle identifier = com.cisco.secureclient.vpn.service
    BTM uuid = 61DCA467-D6AD-4251-90D7-E49891CEAE80
    arguments = {
        vpnagentd
        -execv_instance
    }

    default environment = {
        PATH => /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
    }

    environment = {
        XPC_SERVICE_NAME => com.cisco.secureclient.vpn.service.agent
    }

    domain = system
    minimum runtime = 10
    exit timeout = 45
    runs = 2
    pid = 1987
    immediate reason = inefficient
    forks = 5
    execs = 1
    initialized = 1
    trampolined = 1
    started suspended = 0
    proxy started suspended = 0
    last exit code = 0

    spawn type = daemon (3)
    jetsam priority = 40
    jetsam memory limit (active) = (unlimited)
    jetsam memory limit (inactive) = (unlimited)
    jetsamproperties category = daemon
    submitted job. ignore execute allowed
    jetsam thread limit = 32
    cpumon = default
    job state = running
    probabilistic guard malloc policy = {
        activation rate = 1/1000
        sample rate = 1/0
    }

    properties = partial import | keepalive | abandon process group | resolve program | has LWCR

I can stop this service using the following command:
sudo launchctl bootout system/com.cisco.secureclient.vpn.service.agent

However, when I do that, I cannot re-load the service back again to a state that is recognizable by LaunchControl, nor is it listed in launchctl print system/com.cisco.secureclient.vpn.service.agent
$ launchctl print system/com.cisco.secureclient.vpn.service.agent
Bad request.
Could not find service "com.cisco.secureclient.vpn.service.agent" in domain for system




